# Odd behaviour when using float and CSS columns

Tags: css

I am not sure if this is a bug or not, but shouldn't the dropcap appear in the first column in the example below? Or the whole text wrap on the second column?

How can I force the letter to flow with the text properly?

```
.columns{
    -webkit-column-width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
}

span.dropcaps {
    float: left;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    margin-top: -.09em;
    margin-right: .09em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qLeE/2/

Comment: It depends on many other things, including the "position" of other elements that may be interfering.  I suggest using Chrome or FF Inspect Element, and fiddle with your code there.  It's the best way to troubleshoot odd behaviour in CSS.

Comment: [Why do you need float?](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/8qLeE/14/) What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ZachSaucier It's a dropcap, it needs to be floated...

Comment: @VilmosIoo That comment does nothing to help us understand the effect you want.

Comment: @ZachSaucier sorry. This is the effect I'm looking for http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial Notice how float is suggested as a way to do this.

Comment: @VilmosIoo It has to do with [your margins](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/8qLeE/17/)

Comment: @ZachSaucier that's just luck. It works if the margin is slightly different as well. http://jsfiddle.net/8qLeE/18/ The question is, why doesn't work on all margins? And what does the margin have to do with this? is it a bug or expected behaviour?

Comment: Seems like a bug, though I'm not sure. You might edit your question to ask as such

Comment: "I am not sure if this is a bug or not" -- I did